Sessionless Token With Sabre Profiles
We have automation to manage traveler profiles between our profile system and Sabre Profiles. On occasion, we are receiving TAM usage alerts for exceeding the pool session threshold.
Questions:

Can sessionless tokens/authentication be used with Sabre Profiles SOAP API's?
If "yes" to number 1, is using sessionless tokens a solution to the situation described?
Does Sabre Profiles have REST endpoints?  I could not find any supporting info.

Automation is using session token for calls to Sabre Profiles SOAP API endpoints. All working fine other than occasional excessive usage.  Each call opens/closes session - not using session manager.  Session manager may be only option at present.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I found my answer. There are no REST Sabre Profiles API's and the SOAP Sabre Profiles API's require a session token. In the API documentation Information box for Authentication: Authentication: Session Token
